# Why can a function be called not using its exact name?

Tags: c, function

I found such following function declared in a header file "gobjects.h":

(It is from Stanford Portable Library <gobjects.h>. The source code and header files of the whole library can be found here:
https://github.com/cs50/spl/tree/master/c)

```
/*
 * Function: getWidth
 * Usage: width = getWidth(gobj);
 * ------------------------------
 * Returns the width of this object, which is defined to be the width of
 * the bounding box.
 */

double getWidthGObject(GObject gobj);
```

It confuses me that the name of the function is `getWidthGObject`, but in comment block it specifies the usage as if the name is `getWidth`. And when I call this function in my own code, it seems both names work fine. Just to clarify there is not another function named `getWidth` declared in this header file.

So, my question is, why can we call this function in two different names, while the shorter one of them seems never defined?

Comment: Lol look at [this](https://github.com/cs50/spl/blob/ba36a03713b3686dabdbb4ec43ed9e44c0671ea6/c/include/gtypes.h) source. It has two instances of that. As my dad always says, the one thing you can be sure of with comments is that they're out of date. This looks like a copy paste where they forgot to fix some.

Comment: Sometimes programmers are lazy and don't update comments when they update code.

Comment: Rule: Comments are always wrong.

Comment: @GregHewgill: But the OP tried it, and found that the comment was actually correct. (Well . . . differently wrong.)

Comment: I think what you are suggesting is to adhere to the name of the function in the actual code. But the thing is that I call the function using the name in the comment and it works as well. How to account for this?

Comment: `when I call this function in my own code, it seems both names work fine` You'll need to post (more of) the header file and your code to get an answer to that. Btw, what does the compiler say if you add a line `double (*ptrGetWidth)(GObject) = getWidth;` somewhere?

Comment: Maybe there are *two* functions, with different names? One named `getWidth` and one named `getWidthObject`. Have you tried searching the source code?

Comment: As @Millie Smith says I searched in the "generic.h" file and actually found the getWidth function. But it is wired they have these two functions with similar functionality in two different files. Kind of duplicate.

Comment: @SWang see the end of my answer for why that is. `getWidth` ends up calling `getWidthGObject`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getWidth` is in [generic.h](https://github.com/cs50/spl/blob/ba36a03713b3686dabdbb4ec43ed9e44c0671ea6/c/include/generic.h):

```
#define getWidth(arg) getWidthGeneric(sizeof arg, arg)
```

Comments are often out of date, but it doesn't look like that's the issue here. `getWidthGeneric` ends up calling `getWidthGObject` in [generic.c](https://github.com/cs50/spl/blob/ba36a03713b3686dabdbb4ec43ed9e44c0671ea6/c/src/generic.c). `arg` is constructed with the `...` `va_list`:

```
double getWidthGeneric(int size, ...) {

   ...

   type = getBlockType(arg);
   if (endsWith(type, "GWindow")) {
      return getWidthGWindow((GWindow) arg);
   } else if (endsWith(type, "GObject")) {
      return getWidthGObject((GObject) arg);
   } else {
      error("getWidth: Illegal argument type");
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you also talk about how `getWidthGeneric` is implemented in the corresponding .c file?

Comment: @NickyC What do you want me to say about it?

Comment: How does `getWidthGeneric` find which actual function to call?

Comment: There we go @NickyC. Thanks for pointing out why it was still doing what OP expected.

Comment: To summarize your answer: It is just a way of reproducing function overload in `c`.

Comment: Good point @Holt. I'm relatively new to C and didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: @Millie Smith Yup I now understand what's going on. So I feel like the whole meaning of defining this getWidth function is for convenience (a short name) when being called? sort of encapsulation? thx for solving my puzzle by the way!

Comment: Yep, I think the library authors want you to simply call `getWidth` instead of the longer functions. Simpler and more consistent. You're welcome.